# What means the labels =>, ==>, ===>, ====>, -, -- and a certain number of spaces after them in an output of the command make install?

Tags: compiling, bsd-ports, progress-information

I'm writing a script and I need to mark several blocks of its output. To unify is not bad to use the labels like the output of the command such as `make install`. They are at the beginning of many lines. So I looked some content of the output:

for `=>, ==>, ===>` and `====>`:

```
...
===> Fetching all distfiles required by autoconf-wrapper-20130530 for building
===>  Extracting for autoconf-wrapper-20130530
===>  Patching for autoconf-wrapper-20130530
===>  Configuring for autoconf-wrapper-20130530
===>  Staging for autoconf-wrapper-20130530
===>   Generating temporary packing list
====> Compressing man pages (compress-man)
===>  Building package for autoconf-wrapper-20130530
...
=> SHA256 Checksum OK for pcre-8.33.tar.bz2.
===>  Patching for pcre-8.33
===>  Configuring for pcre-8.33
...
==> You should manually remove the "..." user.
...
```

for `-`:

```
grep -m 3 '^- ' output.txt
```

> - you have a POSIX system
>   - you have jobcontrol
>   - your fifos are usable

for `--`:

```
grep -m 3 '^-- ' output.txt
```

> -- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.2.1
>   -- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.2.1
>   -- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc

Is it commonly accepted labels, if so where are described?
What are the rules put these labels?
Are there any other similar labels?
Why is different the number of spaces after these labels?

Comment: You should add that all these output are coming from package building from **FreeBSD ports**. The messages are more or less related to the various **FreeBSD ports** package building steps, not make by itself.

Comment: @Ouki you're right. Gilles added the appropriate tag, I think that's enough.

Answer (score 1):

This is just to make the output clearer but there is no standard for that. I guess that `=>`, `==>`, `===>` and `====>` are just levels like in a document where you will have titles, and subtitles.

Just simply use what is to your liking if you want to have a nice output.